# How display image in edit form Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have form where i upload files - it work so good, i put image name into database, showing it on main page. But if i want to go to edit information about this image e.g name or description form row with image i have empty and once again i need to upload the same photo:

[edit form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reWnS.jpg)

Project Entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $page_path;

    public function getPhotoPath(): ?string
    {
        return $this->photo_path;
    }

    public function setPhotoPath(string $photo_path): self
    {
        $this->photo_path = $photo_path;

        return $this;
    }
```

ProjectFormType:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Projects;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;

class ProjectsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [])
            ->add('page_path', TextType::class, [])
            ->add('description', TextType::class, [])
            ->add('photo_path', FileType::class, [
                'data_class' => null,
                'label' => 'Zdjęcie',
                'constraints' => [
                    'maxSize' => '5M',
                    'mimeTypes' => [
                        'image/*'
                    ],
                    'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Obsługiwany format pliku musi być obrazem'
                ]
            ]);
          
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Projects::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

View:

```
{% extends 'baseAdmin.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ parent() }}New/Edit
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="card-body">
    
    {% form_theme projectsForm 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' %}
    {{ form_start(projectsForm) }}
    {{ form_row(projectsForm.name) }}
    {{ form_row(projectsForm.page_path) }}
    {{ form_row(projectsForm.description) }}
    {{ form_row(projectsForm.photo_path) }}


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-5">Submit</button>
    {{ form_end(projectsForm) }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File input should be empty when edit your entity and this is the default behavior. to make it required **false** in edit you can use add this simple solution.

```
'required'=> is_null($builder->getData()->getId())
```

if you upload a new image, it should replace the old one, otherwise do nothing.
if you want to show the image, you can do it directly in the twig with `<img>` tag

Comment: Ok i put your code into my $builder in ProjectsType just after `'data_class' => null,` i make thumball of old photo but now if i save the edited 'project' don't changing photo i have an error: `Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "photo_path".
`

Comment: I think because the field is required in your entity I mean in setter  setPropertyPath. try to add ? just after the first parenthese  "(" and try it. if it works so you should find how to make it required only when add new

Comment: `@ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    private $photo_path;    public function getPhotoPath(): ?string
    {
        return $this->photo_path;
    }

    public function setPhotoPath(string $photo_path): self
    {
        $this->photo_path = $photo_path;

        return $this;
    } ` I need to write 'require' in setter just like that : `setPhotoPath(string $photo_path, require) ` ? or in orm annotation ?

Comment: just add "?" `setPhotoPath(?string $photo_path)`  , this is just for test